# Trying to attach an attribute to use with skrollr via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, skrollr

I'm trying to set an attribute to use with skrollr through jQuery, and I don't seem to be having much luck.

html:

```
<section id='section-1' data-0="", data-100p="" class="sections">
```

jQuery:

```
var s = skrollr.init({

});

var section1 = $('#section-1');
var sections = $('.sections');

section1.attr({
"data-0":"transform:translate(0,0%);", 
"data-100p":"transform:translate(0,-50%);"
});

s.refresh(sections);
```

This doesn't seem to be working.. but I'm not 100% sure as to why?

Comment: `section` is getting the attributes. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: it's not showing anything, if I change the opacity to say .5 that doesn't work.. it doesn't seem to be attaching the attribute.

Comment: just setting those attributes will not work... you have have to make skrollr refresh the view... not sure how it is done

Comment: I updated the code to include the refresh, but it didn't seem to make a difference..am I attaching the attribute correctly?